# Issue in converting SQL- Python code to Pyspark-SQL

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

python code which I need to convert to PySpark, But I am new to PySpark(SQL). I am trying to convert my SQL code to PySpark-sql but getting syntax error. Can someone assist me here for PySpark. Below is my Python-SQL code which has successfully executed in Python(Jupyter) code.

```
SQL_query="""
(WITH VCTE_Promotions as (SELECT v.Shortname, v.Employee_ID_ALT, v.Job_Level, 
                         v.Management_Level, CAST(sysdatetime() AS date) AS PIT_Date, v.Employee_Status_Alt as Employee_Status, 
                         v.Work_Location_Region, v.Work_Location_Country_Desc, v.HML, 
                         [DM_GlobalStaff].[dbo].[V_Worker_PIT].Is_Manager
FROM           [DM_GlobalStaff].[dbo].[V_Worker_CUR] as v 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
[DM_GlobalStaff].[dbo].[V_Worker_PIT] ON v.Management_Level = [DM_GlobalStaff].[dbo].[V_Worker_PIT].Management_Level),
VCTE_Promotion_v2_Eval as (
SELECT        Employee_ID_ALT,
                             ( SELECT max([pit_date]) AS prior_data 
                               FROM [DM_GlobalStaff].[dbo].[V_Worker_PIT] AS t
                               WHERE (employee_id_alt = a.Employee_ID_ALT) AND (PIT_Date < a.PIT_Date) AND (Is_Manager <> a.Is_Manager) OR
                                      (employee_id_alt = a.Employee_ID_ALT) AND (PIT_Date < a.PIT_Date) AND (Job_Level <> a.Job_Level)) AS prev_job_change_date, Is_Manager
FROM            VCTE_Promotions AS a)
SELECT  VCTE_Promotion_v2_Eval.Employee_ID_ALT, COALESCE (v_cur.Employee_Status_ALT, N'') AS Curr_Emp_Status, 
                         COALESCE (v_cur.Employee_Type, N'') AS Curr_Employee_Type, v_cur.Hire_Date_Alt AS Curr_Hire_Date, 
                         COALESCE (VCTE_Promotion_v2_Eval.Is_Manager, N'') AS Curr_Ismanager, 
                         CASE WHEN v_m.Job_Level < v_cur.Job_Level OR
                         (VCTE_Promotion_v2_Eval.Is_Manager = 1 AND v_m.Is_Manager = 0 AND v_m.Job_Level <= v_cur.Job_Level) 
                         THEN 'Promotion' WHEN v_m.Job_Level <> v_cur.Job_Level OR
                         VCTE_Promotion_v2_Eval.Is_Manager <> v_m.Is_Manager THEN 'Other' ELSE '' END AS Promotion, v_cur.Tenure, 
                         v_cur.Review_Rating_Current
FROM            VCTE_Promotion_v2_Eval INNER JOIN
                         [DM_GlobalStaff].[dbo].[V_Worker_CUR] as v_cur ON VCTE_Promotion_v2_Eval.Employee_ID_ALT = v_cur.Employee_ID_ALT LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         [DM_GlobalStaff].[dbo].[V_Worker_PIT] as v_m ON VCTE_Promotion_v2_Eval.prev_job_change_date = v_m.PIT_Date AND 
                         VCTE_Promotion_v2_Eval.Employee_ID_ALT = v_m.employee_id_alt
) as pr """

SQL_query= spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=SQL_query, properties=connectionProperties)

SQL_query.count()
```

Error:-

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-448309067524118> in <module>()
----> 1 xpromotions = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=xpromotions, properties=connectionProperties)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in jdbc(self, url, table, column, lowerBound, upperBound, numPartitions, predicates, properties)
    533             jpredicates = utils.toJArray(gateway, gateway.jvm.java.lang.String, predicates)
    534             return self._df(self._jreader.jdbc(url, table, jpredicates, jprop))
--> 535         return self._df(self._jreader.jdbc(url, table, jprop))
    536 
    537 

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1158         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1159         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1160             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1161 
   1162         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    318                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    319                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 320                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    321             else:
    322                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o351.jdbc.
: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1535)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:467)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:409)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:219)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:199)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:331)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:296)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:226)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Edit your question to include the full error message.

Comment: @Shail Your question is very vague. Please edit it by incorporating:
1) Explain what you are trying to do
2) Paste complete stacktrace of the error
3) Explain the code esp till the point you are getting the error.

Comment: Dear all my bad, due to some critical delivery I lost this track. I have updated with error details. Kindly let me know if you need more information from myside.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a lot of things in one query, which won't work out. This is what you are trying to do:

1. Joining table `V_Worker_CUR` and `V_Worker_PIT` and referring it by
   name `VCTE_Promotions`
2. Getting `max(pit_date)` from the above joined table with some filters and referring it as another table named `VCTE_Promotion_v2_Eval`
3. Joining above table `VCTE_Promotion_v2_Eval` with `V_Worker_CUR` and `V_Worker_PIT` and referring it as `pr`

This isn't how spark will work. What is suggest is following:

1. Load individual tables in the spark and store them as dataframes i.e. `V_Worker_CUR` and `V_Worker_PIT`
2. Now either load them as temp table or work on dataframe directly and then join them and perform additional tasks.

The point here is don't write complex query to load the data, rather load the data and then use spark to manipulate it using any language API supported by Spark.